# Transparency on parent div background

Tags: html, css, transparency, opacity

I wonder if it's possible to affect the bg color or opacity of the parent div.

I have a div with this transparent white color:

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
```

The div contains textfields with rounded corners, can the textfields background color in some way be a negative transparency-number so the total opacity of the div and textfield equals 0.5?

Its like mmore transparency in a rounded rec of a already transparent div.

*I have come up with 3 possible solutions:*

1. Make parent dic completely transparent and draw divs as a frame around the fields. (Sounds    very complicated.)
2. Add the content below the div again, inside the textfield. (Performance?)
3. Some kind of intersection.

What do you think I should do?

-- Edit ---

I used a variation of solution #2, I created a png file. Here is the (untweaked)[result](http://anviking.com) (Click contact us to open the modal div). It's hard to see, because of the blur but the window is transparent too.

**Note** this is far from the best solution since one have to update the png when I update the content below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to open a window/hole in the parent `div`. As far as I know, you can't do that, because the `div` is behind the text boxes, and any transparency you apply tho them will cause the `div` to show trough the boxes, NOT the content behind the `div`.

Maybe, instead of a background color, you can make the `div` background a PNG image with two transparent holes that coincide with text boxes, but this is a workaround like yours...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the transparency applied to the outer div will apply to everything inside it. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve here, maybe you should post some more code or a mockup on jsfiddle.

This is what I could find on the subject: http://css-tricks.com/384-non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/

EDIT: For your problem what I would try (I'm not sure if it will work) is follow a similar solution to the link I posted before. Have two separated divs positioned one above the other. I'd recomend you have the form with your transparent inputs on the uper layer, maybe that can do something for you? I don't know what else to tell you, the png solution isn't the best, but you might need to use png's here and there.

Something like this maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/XnATc/21/

Comment: Thank's for you quick answer. Here is a link to a image where I try to show the effect I'm looking for. [Image](http://anviking.com/Images/effect.png) (I apologize If it takes time to load, my web host has performance issues sometimes)

Comment: Hi. The effect you've linked to is most likely generated using a semi-transparent white image as the background that the rounded corner "textbox" lives in. @Elaine is correct. An element that has an opacity rule applied to it will also affect all elements inside it.

Comment: Hi. Note the text box is "cut" from the white box. It may not be shown very well on the image, but the blue on the textfield is the same blue in the background. You can look at my question, I have provided a link to the complete effect. Also, using alpha in the background color won't affect child elements.

Comment: I don't really understand your example. The two boxes is added, not subtracted.

Comment: YEah, you are right, I'm not of much use, I'm sorry :S this look difficult to fix

Comment: I agree, it seems very difficult to fix. :/ I suppose one can just make a transparent white png with a hole in the middle. It's still hard to modify, but not at all as dificult as I made it. However my perticular case, is a other storie, because of the gaussian blur.

Answer (score 0):

Johannes Lund

Yes you should use png image files for this else things gonna be very complicated with hex color coding and its mathematics.